# How to determine the exact httppost action on MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autopostback

this is my action method

```
[HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
           ViewBag.WASELATSAFAR = rep.Get_WASELATSAFAR();
           string EntedabiD = rep.GetID();
           ViewData["ID"] = EntedabiD;
            return View();
        }
```

inside an Entedab Controller

Html

```
 <div class="form-actions fluid" style="    margin-top: 87px;">
                        <div class="portlet-body">
                            <div class="table-toolbar">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <a id="AddEmployee" class="btn green">
                                        <span style="font-size: 18px !important; font-family: -webkit-body; "> اضافة موظف</span>
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="AllEmployees">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                            serial
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="width: 200px;">
                                            Name
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Fia
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Degree
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Salary
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Transportation
                                        </th>

                                        <th>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="AddedEmployees">
                                    @Html.Partial("_Employees")
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and I tried to surround the Html by this @using (Html.BeginForm())
like that

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

     <div class="form-actions fluid" style="    margin-top: 87px;">
                            <div class="portlet-body">
                                <div class="table-toolbar">
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <a id="AddEmployee" class="btn green">
                                            <span style="font-size: 18px !important; font-family: -webkit-body; "> Add Emp</span>
                                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="AllEmployees">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                serial
                                            </th>
                                            <th style="width: 200px;">
                                                Name
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Fia
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Degree
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Salary
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                               Transportation
                                            </th>

                                            <th>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="AddedEmployees">
                                        @Html.Partial("_Employees")
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
}
```

the problem is when I click this submit input it goes to the [HttpGet] action method but I want it to go to this one

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Entedab_Index(EntedabViewModel entedabObj)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                rep.add(entedabObj);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

THE INPUT SUBMIT BUTTON

```
 <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn green btn-lg" 
                                   style=" float: left; font-family: -webkit-body; font-size: 20px; width: 200px;">
```

I am trying-

```
    [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Entedab_Index(){
        ViewBag.WASELATSAFAR = rep.Get_WASELATSAFAR();
         string EntedabiD = rep.GetID();
         ViewData["ID"] = EntedabiD;
         return View();
        } 


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Entedab_Index(EntedabViewModel entedabObj)
     {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
    rep.add(entedabObj); 
    } 
    return RedirectToAction("Entedab_Index");
    }




@using (Html.BeginForm("Entedab_Index", "Entedab",FormMethod.Post)) {//html}
```

but gives this error "An item with the same key has already been added"

Comment: Your error nothing has to do with the actions that you mentioned below.
Can you check in `EntedabViewModel` class whether you have 2 or more properties with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change-

```
 [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Entedab_Index(EntedabViewModel entedabObj)
```

To

```
 [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Index(EntedabViewModel entedabObj)
```

Then it will post to current request's post method.

Another way is to give it the defined url as-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action","Controller",HttpMethod.Post))
{
}
```

Comment: public ActionResult Entedab_Index()//int? page, string name
{ViewBag.WASELATSAFAR = rep.Get_WASELATSAFAR();
 string EntedabiD = rep.GetID();  ViewData["ID"] = EntedabiD;
            return View(); }        [HttpPost] public ActionResult Entedab_Index(EntedabViewModel entedabObj)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                rep.add(entedabObj);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Entedab_Index");

        }
@using (Html.BeginForm("Entedab_Index", "Entedab",FormMethod.Post))
{}
gives this error "An item with the same key has already been added"

Comment: @Asp.NetDeveloper, can you please edit this in question?